# Issue with using Omit option

Tags: ansible, arguments, jinja2, f5, omittag

I am trying configure a attribute only if my_int_http is defined else I dont want it. So I coded it like below:

```yaml
profiles:
      - "{{ my_int_L4 }}"
      - "{{ my_int_http | default(omit) }}"
```

However my execution fail and when check the arguments passed by the code in actual configuration it shows like below:

```
 "profiles": [
                "my_example.internal_tcp",
                "__omit_place_holder__ef8c5b99e9707c044ac07fda72fa950565f248a4"
```

So how to pass absolutely no value where it is passing `__omit_place_holder_****`?

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*How to pass absolutely no value where it is passing *omit_place_holder* ?*"**

A1: Some [filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) also work with *omit* as expected. For example, the play

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test:
      - "{{ var1|default(false) }}"
      - "{{ var1|default(omit) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ {'a': item}|combine({'b': true}) }}"
      loop: "{{ test }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
    a: false
    b: true

  msg:
    b: true
```

As a sidenote, *default(omit)* is *defined* type *string*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item is defined }}"
      loop: "{{ test }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item|type_debug }}"
      loop: "{{ test }}"
```

give

```yaml
TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=False) => 
  msg: true
ok: [localhost] => (item=__omit_place_holder__6e56f2f992faa6e262507cb77410946ea57dc7ef) => 
  msg: true

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=False) => 
  msg: bool
ok: [localhost] => (item=__omit_place_holder__6e56f2f992faa6e262507cb77410946ea57dc7ef) => 
  msg: str
```

---

A2: No value in Ansible is YAML [*null*](https://yaml.org/type/null.html). Quoting:

> *This is typically converted into any native null-like value (e.g., undef in Perl, None in Python).*

(Given *my_int_L4=bob*). If the variable *my_int_http* defaults to *null* instead of *omit*

```yaml
profiles:
      - "{{ my_int_L4 }}"
      - "{{ my_int_http | default(null) }}"
```

the list *profiles* will be *undefined*

```yaml
  profiles: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
```

Use *None* instead

```yaml
profiles:
      - "{{ my_int_L4 }}"
      - "{{ my_int_http | default(None) }}"
```

The variable *my_int_http* will default to an empty string

```yaml
  profiles:
  - bob
  - ''
```

See also section "YAML tags and Python types" in [PyYAML Documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation).

Comment: I love these answers. I'm learning something new every day by just reading your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
profiles:
      - "{{ my_int_L4 }}"
      - "{{ my_int_http | default(None) }}"
```

This will give you an empty string. And you can add a check while iterating over the profiles.

Please have a look at this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/44261) to get more understanding.